# How to make COM DoDragAndDrop API be touch sensitive on Windows 7/8?

Tags: winapi, com, drag-and-drop, touch

On Windows, the drag and drop action can be done via COM DoDragAndDrop API, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/desktop/ms678486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. It can perform D&D operation perfectly and has the best system integration.

Recently, I found it is not touch friendly API, it can not handle touch event very well. On Window 7/8, A Win32 window created by CreateWindow API is also able to handle touch event in the same way as handling mouse event. Actullay, it seems the touch events are converted into a similar mouse events, e.g. a mouse down event is triggered when a finger is tapped down, a mouse move event is triggered when a finger is moved.

However, the DoDragAndDrop COM API doesn't convert touch event into mouse event, even the COM service doesn't have any idea about touch event at all. But I had a try to drag a file from one folder to another folder on Win8, it works. If the D&D operation is also implemented based on COM API, I indeed got a conflicting result.

Did I miss something when I use DoDragAndDrop for touch event support? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`DoDragDrop()` does support touch on Win7/8 (and yes, D&D of files is implemented by Windows Explorer using `DoDragDrop()`), so your problem is related to something else.  Did you check whether `DoDragDrop()` is returning any error code to your code that you may be ignoring?